# Alternative to Selenium Grid Console?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, grid

Does anyone know of any alternative to Selenium Grid's console?

We are thinking about building our own console. What I was asking was, are there any alternatives out there for the default Selenium console?

Comment: What functions of the console should it provide?

Comment: There is an API and a protocol.  You can build your alternative.

Comment: I'd agree with Niels, it's probably worth giving some idea of what functionality you need or you'll either get no answers, or pretty random ones. I'll put this on hold for new answers to give you the time to add a bit more information.

Comment: I have a same problem. I can't install "Sélénium Grid" on server. Do you have any other solution ? (to launch IE on client)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to parse Grid Console's JSON response and then output it in your format.

You could look at [selenium-grid-status](https://github.com/davglass/selenium-grid-status) project as an example.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to Selenium Grid itself compatible with WebDriver protocol (so don't need to change tests). It consists of two pieces:

1. [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid) - a lightweight Selenium server replacement having a standalone user interface - [Selenoid UI](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid-ui). UI receives all information via HTTP `/status` API so you can create your own UI if needed. Selenoid is implemented in [Golang](https://golang.org/) and is slightly more performant than Java-based Selenium server.
2. [GoGridRouter](https://github.com/aerokube/ggr) (aka Ggr) - a fast load balancer for Selenium infrastructure.

**NOTE:** I am one of the core maintainers of these projects.